# I have three column in a row but when I put value in first column it automatically goes to all the other two columns

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, arrays, controller

As a beginner I don't have quality of knowledge regarding AngularJS and array so I am putting this question here. I have three column in a row named 'near metro station', 'longitude', 'latitude' but when I put value in first column it automatically goes to all the other two columns. How can I put it into a single array and fill all the columns Separately?

**HTML:**

```
                        <div class="input-field col s12 m4">
                            <input id="near_metro" type="text" data-ng-model="location.connectivity[17]" value="17" name="location.connectivity[17]">
                            <label for="near_metro" class="">Near Metro Station</label>
                        </div>

                        <div class="input-field col s12 m3 ">
                            <input id="metro_long"  type="text" data-ng-model="location.connectivity[17]">
                            <label for="metro_long" class="">Longitude</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="input-field col s12 m3 ">
                            <input id="metro_lat" type="text" data-ng-model="location.connectivity[17]">
                            <label for="metro_lat" class="">Latitude</label>
                        </div>
```

**Controller:**

```
  nearmetros: [{

name: '',
                long: '',
                lat: '',

            }],

 addMetro: function () 
{

$scope.nearmetros.push({
                    name: '',
                    long: '',
                    lat: '',

                })
            },
```

**Image:**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zYalw.png)

Comment: First of all change the name of all controller eg. location.name, location.longitude, location.latitude.. and name sholud be dropdown or autocomplete to select location... so that you can fill other two field based on name selection

Comment: in that way it's working but i want to pass all the value from array so that it would be easy for me to store the values in the database. like i can add more rows e.g. hospital, atm, movie theatre etc. etc.

Comment: How foolish were I at that time :(

Answer (score 0):

Change the `data-ng-model="location.connectivity[17]"` to the values you want to use.

It is unclear from your code what values you are trying to use.
Are you sure you want to directly assign the values instead of using `ng-repeat` ?

Comment: i want to fill the values from user end and in connectivity[17]. 17 is unique id in the database for near metro.